# How to use lambda expressions for a function that takes a list of delegates

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I'm building an extension method on IList to be able to output the specified properties of any object passed into it as a list, and output it as a CSV string. It looks like:

```
public static string OutputCSVString<T>(this IList<T> list, List<Func<T, string>> properties)
{
   foreach (var row in list)
   {
     foreach(var item in properties)
     { 
        // Do the output work, including calling item(row).
     }
      // Output new line
   }
 }
```

Right now, I have to call this method like:

```
// Assuming I've populated List <Product> ProductList up above...

var columns = new List<Func<Product, string>>();
columns.Add(x => x.Id);
columns.Add(x => x.Name);

string s = ProductList.OutputCSVString(columns);
```

Is there a better way to pass in my lambda expressions without having to explicitly declare the columns variable, something like:

```
// This doesn't compile
string s = Products.OutputCSVString(new { p => p.Id , p => p.Name });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using a `List<Func<T, string>>` use a `Func<T, string>[]` and make it a [parameter array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
static string OutputCSVString<T>(this IList<T> list,
                                 params Func<T, string>[] properties)
```

Then you should be able to call:

```
string s = Products.OutputCSVString(p => p.Id , p => p.Name);
```

Note that as of C# 6, you should be able to write:

```
static string OutputCSVString<T>(this IList<T> list,
                                 params IEnumerable<Func<T, string>> properties)
```

... which would mean you could still use it with a `List<Func<T, string>>` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try passing in as a params array

```
public static string OutputSVString<T>(this IList<T> list, params Func<T, string>[] properties)
{
    ...
}
```

This will let you invoke it as

```
var s = Products.OutputCSVString(p => p.Id, p => p.Name);
```

Also, as a suggestion, loosen up the function return to an object and then call ToString() when assembling the parts.  This way you can pass in any property to include in the CSV list, not just strings.

Answer (score 4):

You could pass your lambdas as an array and use the `params` keyword:

```
public static string OutputCSVString<T>(this IList<T> list, params Func<T, string>[] properties)
```

Usage:

```
string s = Products.OutputCSVString(p => p.Id, p => p.Name);
```